# Django Heroku how to go back to development server to make more changes

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-deployment, django-dev-server

So I just deployed my Django app to Heroku, and everything is working fine. The current version of the app isn't perfect, so I want to edit it, but my current process is:

```
1. **make changes in files
2. git status (just to make sure changes are seen)
3. git add -A
4. git commit -m "message"
5. git push heroku master
```

How can I get back the whole `python manage.py runserver` development part so I can be more thorough with my changes, and only commit when I know the changes meet my expectations?

Since I'm new to Python/HTML/CSS, I'm always coding then testing to see what my code does, and it would involve a lot of `git commit / git push` currently. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

deploying to Heroku should not stop you from using `python manage.py runserver`. Just make sure that you have loaded up your virtual environment (if you are using one) and it should just work.

Comment: Before I was getting an error when I ran runserver, but now there is no error, but opening the localhost gives me a server error 500 on any page. Any idea why this may be?